# Glassfish step by step hot deploy

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, glassfish-3, glassfish-4

Hello i would like ask how it is possible configure `glassfish` server for something like live, hot deployment:

every time when i change some code of my `jsp`,`html`,`js` or `css` file i always need to clean and build project than deploy project to `glassfish` and again, again and again. That cost a lot of my time. I waste time for that. It will be easy when i could work on files which already use a started glasfish (deployed). But this files is in WAR file "`project.war`" and through my `IDE (`Netbeans`)` i cant edit this files (`jsp`,`css`,html or js). `Netbeans` made this file non editable.

Do you have idea how to speed up my development? I Will grateful for help.

Here is my glasfish home folder and all of 2 deployed applications are empty

[image]

Comment: If you have configured your Glassfish instance in Netbeans (7+ ? not sure)  and run the project from Netbeans the project will redeploy on file change (Project properties - Run - Deploy on Save)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can. if you need change xhtml, js, css only you can do this after your war was deployed. You can find all the files in the folder of your application
****\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\MyWebApplication\
when you complete your changes you need copy them to project folder and rebuild war

Comment: this location i have empty after deployed. MyWebApplication exists but is empty. Meaby i should do something?

Comment: In my sample I used "domain1" - but it's possible that you have more than 1 domain and your application was deployed to let say domain2

Comment: I update my base post on printscreen of my glasfish home location. As I said before i have these folder empty. But applications works fine.